# How can i find all Pages which Title start between A-F

Tags: 2007

Please advise me how can i write Query to get all Items from Pages library to find all pages which Title start from A-F.

Thanks
Ronak

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<BeginsWith>` CAML operator: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476051(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476051%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: And chain multiple of them (A through F) with OR

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to to a simple alphanumeric comparison, like filter all pages where Title > "A!" and Title < "G!"